# Is there a race condition in the code of this Parallel Forall blogopost?

Tags: cuda

I've recently stumbled upon this blogpost in the NVIDIA devblogs: 
https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/accelerating-graph-betweenness-centrality-cuda/

I´ve implented the edge parallel code and it seems to work as intended, however it seems to me that the code works with a race condition "controlled" with __syncthreads. 
This is the code (as shown in the blog):

```
__shared__ int current_depth;
__shared__ bool done;

if(idx == 0){
    done = false;
    current_depth = 0;
}
__syncthreads();

// Calculate the number of shortest paths and the 
// distance from s (the root) to each vertex
while(!done){
    __syncthreads();
    done = true;
    __syncthreads();

for(int k=idx; k<m; k+=blockDim.x) //For each edge...
{
    int v = F[k];
    // If the head is in the vertex frontier, look at the tail
    if(d[v] == current_depth) 
    {
        int w = C[k];
        if(d[w] == INT_MAX){
            d[w] = d[v] + 1;
            done = false;
        }
        if(d[w] == (d[v] + 1)){
            atomicAdd(&sigma[w],sigma[v]);
        }
    }
    __syncthreads();
    current_depth++;
    }
}
```

I think there is a race condition just at the end:

```
__syncthreads();
current_depth++;
```

I think the program is relying on the race condition so the variable gets increased only by one, instead of by the number of threads. I don't feel like this is a good idea, but in my tests it seems to be reliable. 
Is this really safe? Is there a better way to do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the author of this blog post, I'd like to thank you for pointing out this error!

When I wrote this snippet I didn't use my verbatim edge-traversal code as that used explicit queuing to traverse the graph which makes the example more complicated without adding any pedagogical value. Instead I must have cargo-culted some old code and posted it incorrectly. It's been quite a while since I've touched this code or algorithm, but I believe the following snippet should work:

```
__shared__ int current_depth;
__shared__ bool done;

if(idx == 0){
    done = false;
    current_depth = 0;
}
__syncthreads();

// Calculate the number of shortest paths and the 
// distance from s (the root) to each vertex
while(!done)
{
    __syncthreads();
    done = true;
    __syncthreads();

    for(int k=idx; k<m; k+=blockDim.x) //For each edge...
    {
        int v = F[k];
        // If the head is in the vertex frontier, look at the tail
        if(d[v] == current_depth) 
        {
            int w = C[k];
            if(d[w] == INT_MAX){
                d[w] = d[v] + 1;
                done = false;
            }
            if(d[w] == (d[v] + 1)){
                atomicAdd(&sigma[w],sigma[v]);
            }
        }
    }
    __syncthreads(); //All threads reach here, no longer UB
    if(idx == 0){ //Only one thread should increment this shared variable
        current_depth++;
    }
}
```

Notes:

1. Looks like a similar issue exists in the node parallel algorithm on the blog post
2. You could also use a register instead of a shared variable for current_depth, in which case every thread would have to increment it

So to answer your question, no, that method is not safe. If I'm not mistaken the blog snippet has the additional issue that `current_depth` should only be incremented once all vertices at the previous depth were handled, which is at the conclusion of the for loop.

Finally, if you'd like the final version of my code that has been tested and used by people in the community, you can access it here: https://github.com/Adam27X/hybrid_BC

Comment: I've updated the code in the blog post to match Adam's correction above. Thanks @MeyerM for reporting.